# can i add a new page in wordpress as like add link html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
                        <li>
                            <a href="about_us.php">
                                About us
                            </a>

                        </li>
```

this is my code and about_us.php is fully supported by wordpress but when i click in about us button then say page not found

[image: 1]

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/get-page-link-from-slug

Comment: What's the full URL that shows once you've clicked on the link? Also, what's the relative path of the about_us.php file from the webroot?

Comment: you can create a page by going in admin panel, `create new page` and it will show in you page list

Comment: you need to create a page first then check the slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new Page, log in to your WordPress installation with sufficient admin privileges to create new articles. Select the Administration > Pages > Add New option to begin writing a new Page.
For More details refer the below links

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages_Add_New_Screen

Comment: i am actually want just link about_us.php and when i click About us  button then go about_us.php page is it possible ?

Comment: you can use the full path of the page as link (sitename/about_us.php)
 <a href="sitename/about_us.php">

Comment: i use  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about_us.php">About Us</a> is it right ? or use  <a href="about_us.php">About Us</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can add the page in the existing navigation menu.